# Is there a way to remove the id column in a subsequent Rails 3 ActiveRecord migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 3 ActiveRecord create_table is it possible to include the option :id => false. For example

```
create_table :posts, :id => false do |t|
...
end
```

but is it possible to remove the :id column on an existing table in a subsequent up migration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to remove the column just like any other non-id column:

```
remove_column :posts, :id
```