# Overwriting the id column in a Rails table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an app on top of data that I already have, I got it from the client as .mdb file (MS Access). It consists of multiple tables T1, T2, ..., TN.

What I did so far : convert the Access tables to CSV, created my Rails table t1 thanks to a script, but the ids are not right
What I want to do : create a Rails table for each of the tables T1 thru TN
Problem : I don't know how to get rid of the default Rails id column, that is auto-increment

Details :
I have table T1 with attributes (t1_id, name, email, phone)
Say I have 3 tuples in it : (3, Foo, foo@g.com, 0000) (9, Bar, bar@g.com, 1111) (32, Baz, baz@g.com, 2222)
The ids, as I have them, are not a neat sequence 1, 2, 3 - there must have been deletions at some point. 
I know how to populate my Rails table using the CSV, using this script :

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('./db/seeds/file.csv', headers: true) do |row|
    p row   #p = advanced toString
    p T1.create(id: row['\xEF\xBB\xBFT1ID'], first_name: row['FirstName'], phone: row['Phone'], email: row['Email'])
end
```

As you notice, my CSV header is a bit weird, I have some unicode characters hanging there...
Anyways, my model is the following, taken from schema.rb :

```
create_table "t1", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "phone"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",       :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       :null => false
end
```

After running the script, my table has the following tuples, with the wrong IDs:
(1, Foo, foo@g.com, 0000) (2, Bar, bar@g.com, 1111) (3, Baz, baz@g.com, 2222)

How can I get the IDs right ?
Thaaaanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :id column is not accessible for mass assignment. Try to set it apart:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('./db/seeds/file.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  p row   #p = advanced toString
  record = T1.new(first_name: row['FirstName'], phone: row['Phone'], email: row['Email'])
  record.id = row['\xEF\xBB\xBFT1ID']
  p record.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394253/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-id-column-in-a-subsequent-rails-3-activerecord-migr) you should run a Rails migration

```
def up
   remove_column :t1, :id
end
```